# Bundle Format is Ambiguous OSX app

Tags: macos

In terminal I ran:

codesign -f --verbose --deep --strict -s "Developer ID"  /File.Path.app

I get back:

/File.Path.app: bundle format is ambiguous (could be app or framework)

In subcomponent /File.Path.app/Contents/Frameworks/AppCenterCrashes.framework

Things I have tried:

In the AppCenterCrashes.framework, I was able to code sign the folders subfolders (Image attached)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHKGp.png) but not sure why I cant code sign the .app so that I can upload it to Appcenter and have it code signed.

Used Ditto command to copy the files from the .xarchive so that I could get a .zip file to upload.

Any Help?